# Check box value is not getting captured from grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get read values from GridView and upload into database

I am able to read the text value but unable to get the GridView CheckBox value ..

I am getting only `false (0)` in database table while running the following code in asp.C#

My Code at Button Event is as follows :-

```
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnSave.Visible = false;
        btnEdit.Visible = true;
        int i = 0;
        string defaultvalue = "0";
        foreach (GridViewRow row in grdExtApp.Rows)
        {
            string qry = "INSERT into tb_externalsystemaccess(User_Id,     SystemName,Access_status) VALUES (@v1, @v2, @v3)";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v1", TextBox3.Text);    
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@v2", SqlDbType.Text).Value = Convert.ToString    (row.Cells[0].Text);
                CheckBox chkBx = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("AccessExternal");
                if (chkBx.Checked)
                {
                    defaultvalue = "1";
                }
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@v3", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Convert.ToInt16    (defaultvalue);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                i = i + 1;

            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting the v1 value from outside TextBox control.

v2 value is from GridView cell ..it is a string value and I am able to capture it

v3 value is CheckBox value ..it is not able capture ..instead shows only as false even though I check the CheckBox.

My markup for GridView looks like this:

```
     <asp:GridView ID="grdExtApp" runat="server" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White">
                          <Columns>
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="External_System"       HeaderText="External System" />  



                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Access">  

                      <ItemTemplate>  

                          <asp:CheckBox ID="AccessExternal" runat="server"      Enabled="true" />  

                   </ItemTemplate>  

                 </asp:TemplateField>  


                          </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
```

Please help me why I am unable to get the checkbox value

Comment: Have you debugged `btnSave_Click()` to make sure that the checkbox truly isn't checked?

Comment: loop is not entering inside the if condition even if I checked the check box..seems check box control is not accessible..thouhg it does not show any error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`btn_Save()` is a postback method, I am postulating in your `Form_Load()` you are always rebinding your grid, thereby clearing out your checked checkboxes.

You should have this at the top of your `Form_Load()`:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        grdExtApp.DataSourceID = "yourDatasourceID";
        grdExtApp.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnSave.Visible = false;
        btnEdit.Visible = true;
        //int i = 0;
        //string defaultvalue = "0";

         string qry = "INSERT into tb_externalsystemaccess(User_Id,SystemName,Access_status) VALUES (@v1, @v2, @v3)";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
              for (int i = 0; i < grdExtApp.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                GridViewRow row = grdExtApp.Rows[i];
                bool defaultvalue  = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("AccessExternal")).Checked;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v1", TextBox3.Text);    
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@v2", SqlDbType.Text).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@v3", SqlDbType.Bit).Value =defaultvalue;
                con.open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();

            }

    }
```

Comment: Not working still shows as false..seems check boxvalue is not accessible